# ReactJS useReducer filter functions directly in the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm looking into React Hooks and I encountered a question while using React Reducer.

Is it a good way to directly define filter functions in the state for the respective state? Or does it destroy the mental programming model?

```
import ...

export const ExpensesContext = createContext([]);

const initialState = {
    Expenses: [],
    // 
    GetExpensesFromCategory(category: string) {
        return this.Expenses.filter(i => i.Category === category)
    }
};

function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "update":
            return {...state, ...action.payload};
        case "delete":
            return {};
    }

    return state;
}

const ExpensesStore = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    const [userState] = useContext(UserContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        // some behaviour
    }, [userState]);

    return (
        <ExpensesContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
            {children}
        </ExpensesContext.Provider>
    )
};

export default ExpensesStore;
```

Comment: Since GetExpensesFromCategory is on the same object as Expenses (in JS usually only constructor functions start with capital) why don't you write a function: `export const filterByCategory(expenses,category)=>category.filter(expense => expense.Category === category)`. As a rule of thumb' if you have to use `this` with React you really have to think twice. If it works for you then that's fine but other programmers having to maintain your code may get confused.

Comment: Okay, I get it. I noticed that you can't rely 100 percent on the fact that the functions exist. If it is accidentally overwritten in an update or something else.

But in the following, the question arises where I usually store such functions. Is there a common way to store them? Do I create a new file that contains all the functions or do I put it directly into the storage?

Comment: Normally you would put them in [selectors](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect), selectors can either just select something from state like `const selectData = state=>state.data`, select something specific from state like `const createSelectEntitytype(entityType)=>createSelector(selectData,(_,entityType)=>entityType,(data,entityType)=>data[entityType])` and in your component you can create a memoized selector: `const selectType=React.useMemo(()=>createSelector(props.entityType),[props.entityType])` or morph data `createSelector(selectPeople,pp=>pp.map(p=>({...p,fullName:p.first+p.last})))`

Comment: It looks like you a more familiar with C# so maybe Angular would be a better fit for you but if you want/have to take on React it would be good to investigate functional programming. Especially pure functions, immutability and memoization.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'll take a closer look at functional programming in relation to ReactJs (Hooks). Does anyone know a resource (book, video..)?

Comment: Pure functions, immutability and memoization are not react specific and should have articles related to JavaScript available. I think you can study reselect (will give you memoization automatically) documentation and the react hooks documentation